# Tkinter object collision?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So I've made a "game" that has 2 balls a green ball and a red one you can move the red ball around but when it collides with the green ball I want it to display a success message by printing in the console! Heres my code.

```
__author__ = 'Zac'
from Tkinter import *
from random import randint
class Application:
    def circle(self, r, x, y):
        return (x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r)

    def square(self, s, x, y):
        return (x, y, s, s)

    def __init__(self, canvas, r, x, y, **kwargs):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.r = r
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.ball = canvas.create_oval(self.circle(r, x, y), **kwargs)


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 1000, height = 1000)
canvas.pack()

ball1 = Application(canvas, 20, 50, 50, fill='red')
ball2 = Application(canvas, 30, 200, 250, fill='green')

def forward(event):
    canvas.delete(ball1.ball)
    ball1.y -= 5
    ball1.ball = canvas.create_oval(ball1.circle(ball1.r, ball1.x, ball1.y), fill='red')

def backward(event):
    canvas.delete(ball1.ball)
    ball1.y += 5
    ball1.ball = canvas.create_oval(ball1.circle(ball1.r, ball1.x, ball1.y), fill='red')

def left(event):
    canvas.delete(ball1.ball)
    ball1.x -= 5
    ball1.ball = canvas.create_oval(ball1.circle(ball1.r, ball1.x, ball1.y), fill='red')

def right(event):
    canvas.delete(ball1.ball)
    ball1.x += 5
    ball1.ball = canvas.create_oval(ball1.circle(ball1.r, ball1.x, ball1.y), fill='red')

root.bind('<w>', forward)
root.bind('<s>', backward)
root.bind('<a>', left)
root.bind('<d>', right)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You will need to write a function that checks if the objects are close enough to be touching, then call that function at the end of every move.

Comment: To do that, you create an imaginary right triangle, the hypotenuse being the distance between the centers of the balls.  You can then get the x side=difference between the ball's x coordinates, and the same for the y side and use the standard right triangle formula a**2+b**2=c**2 to find the distance between the centers. If it is less than the sum of the radii then there is a collision.

Comment: @CurlyJoe could you give an example since I find that hard to understand :P

Comment: The functions forward, backward, left, and right should all go in the class, so each ball has it's own set of movement functions.  You can then bind other keys to the 2nd ball, or add an additional event that will change the bindings from one ball to the next.

Comment: x_diff=abs(ball2.x-ball1.x).  Same for y.  The site changed the formula above but it is a^2+b^2=c^2

Comment: What is your question? You've told us what you want but you haven't said what you need help with.

Comment: @BryanOakley I need help making the fucntion to say if the red ball collided with the green ball...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so heres how I did it!

I added this function

```
def collide():
    x_diff = abs(ball1.x - ball2.x)
    y_diff = abs(ball1.y - ball2.y)

    if x_diff <= 49:
        if y_diff <= 49:
            print "COLLIDED"
```

And everytime you run the function to move the collision function is called and if there touching it prints "Collided"

Thx to @CurlyJoe for the code for checking the distance between them!